# Allow only a certain number of markers in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I am playing with google maps (android studio), and trying to limit the number of markers a single user can pin. I couldn't find any examples online, only thing I could find is removing the current marker (code below).

My goal is to allow the user to pin only 3 markers.

```
     mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
            //if there is a marker already this if condition removes it
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_02))
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                    arg0.longitude))
                    .draggable(true).visible(true));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do the map has method like getScreenMarkers? or you can store all marker you add in a List.

Comment: There is no method like getScreenMarkers, I would store all the markers in the list. Shwet's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int marker_count=0;   
     mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
                    if(marker_count<3){
    //if there is a marker already this if condition removes it

                   if (marker != null) {
                        marker.remove();
marker_count=marker_count-1;
                    }
marker_count=marker_count+1;
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_02))
                            .position(
                                    new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                            arg0.longitude))
                            .draggable(true).visible(true));
                }}
    else{
    //toast a message
    }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. This worked. Edited it a little bit to disable adding a fourth marker instead of deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Shvet's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34106897/5643914) a little bit. After pinning 3 markers user is unable to pin fourth, and he gets a quick message.

```
int markerCount = 0; //marker counter

mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        if (markerCount < 3) {
            markerCount = markerCount+ 1;
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))
                    .position(new LatLng(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude))
                    .draggable(true)
                    .visible(true));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only 3 markers allowed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```